# DB design to avoid versioning inconsistencies between the application layer and the database layer

Tags: database-design, application-design, orm, data-tier-application

Usually there is a 1-1 mapping between an object in the application layer and a table in the database layer.
This coupling leads to complexities whenever there is a database schema change and the application version may not be compatible with the current database version that it is talking to.
I was reading that there is an approach of database design that is driven by metadata. Something like the fields available for an object is found from a table and then a query is done. So some form of direction in order to avoid versioning problems.
Is this approach used in general and how exactly is it implemented? Also are there are other approaches to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you're think of is called Entity-Attribute=Value (EAV). If you Google around for it you'll find very quickly that it is almost universally reviled.  In short, it's generally a bad idea because it doesn't let your relational database management system do what it was designed to do.

As an alternative, you should think about schema changes as something that you need to keep backward compatible.  This often means that new columns will be nullable or have defaults set.  Depending on what you want to do with your application, though, sometimes a database change is simply a breaking change and you can't release the database change without releasing the corresponding code change.

I've seen some people keep a short code table in their database that contains version information in it (e.g. minimum and maximum supported code versions). The idea with this is that when your application starts it does a quick lookup in the code table and if the database version isn't compatible with the code the code exits gracefully.

Comment: Thank you and upvoted! If new columns are added then isn't the change backwards compatible by default? Previous app version would just not be using the columns as they would be unknown. Or am I missing something? But what about removing columns? That is what I am trying to address. I'll read into the EAV but for my case I don't really need the relational part due to not having many tables of FK constraints and I mostly focused on app upgrades and performance. Would that be a good use case for EAV?

Comment: @Jim If you add a mandatory column without a default that would be a breaking change.  If you add a column that needs to be populated to support a downstream system (say a reporting system) then that _could_ be a breaking change. Removing a column is likely to be a breaking change. The only way to avoid it that I can think of would be to trap for the error a missing column would generate and degrade gracefully, or even continue running. I don't know that I'd do something like that though, it seems too risky and a lot of work for something that hopefully is very rare.

Comment: @Jim As for good use cases for EAV, I've argued [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231834/if-eav-is-evil-what-to-use-for-dynamic-values/17233204#17233204) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779252/entity-attribute-value-table-design/11972029#11972029) that "EAV is Evil" - except when it isn't.  For example in an online shopping product catalog.

Comment: Ah I see. By `trap for the error a missing column would generate ` you mean like a `try/catch` in the app level?

Comment: Also I found this example for EAV https://blog.greglow.com/2018/02/12/sql-design-entity-attribute-value-tables-part-1/ but does not seem to take into account the version of the object (e.g. `People`). Is versioning not something addressed by EAV? I am confused in that aspect

Comment: @Jim Yes, I meant trap for the error and handle it gracefully.  About EAV and versioning, what it gives you is the ability to tag attributes (columns) with extra information, such as minimum/maximum app version to support.  In an EAV design the metadata that you typically have in the database definition, like column name, column size, data type, etc. is made more explicit in the metadata tables themselves.  It's like building your database code to easily support Reflection. Taking away a column in an EAV situation is still going to break your code unless you have some other code to handle it.

Comment: `Taking away a column in an EAV situation is still going to break your code` Why? If I understood the EAV, we get the object's field from a table. So if an older version does `person.get("department_id")` then if the table for `Person` does not have `department_id` anymore then the result is `null`. Why would it break?

Comment: @Jim, it depends on what happens with your code when you call for something that isn't there. Does your code degrade gracefully when encountering a Null? Is your code checking EAV metadata in advance so that it doesn't ask for something that isn't there? Is there a business rule in your code that can't be tested/operated without that missing field?  There is no magical answer to taking things out of your database. You need a design approach that you carefully consider and implement if you want to have robust code, whether you use EAV or normal relational tables.

Comment: Do you have a good reference of EAV that shows some implementation? Most online resources I found are too verbose and show much theory

Comment: @Jim I don't have a practical guide to EAV. Most people in most cases consider it an anti-pattern, so it's not the sort of thing that many people would consider writing.